# Upload file in django plotly don't working

Tags: django, plotly, plotly-dash

I build a module to analyze a file and return a plotly graphic. Now i need to implement im django template, but can't integrate a upload file in my plotly module. I can make the upload and the function it's working, but i can't using together.

The situation is: I need a to upload a file, make the analyze with a plotly function and return a graphic.

This is my django view code:

```
def test_page(request):
    directory = 'C:\\tmp\\Uploads\\'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=directory)
        filename = upload_file.name
        url = fs.url(upload_file)
        file = directory + filename
        print(file)


#plotly function

        UFLGplots = visualization_Django_Dash.build_GRplots(file)

        context = {
            
            'UFLGplots': UFLGplots,
        }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

When i make the runserver the firt error is The varible file is empty. I want to call the plotly function just when i make the upload file.